# pragmatically add items to dropdownlist in detailsview update mode and bind the data

Tags: c#, asp.net

i have a detailview with a dropdownlist

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="nid" SortExpression="nid">
                <EditItemTemplate>
                    <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server" onclick="btnUpdate_Click">
                    </asp:DropDownList>
                </EditItemTemplate>
                <InsertItemTemplate>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("nid") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                </InsertItemTemplate>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("nid") %>'></asp:Label>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
```

i want to add the items when using click the update button than bind the data to the dropdownlist

here is the functions

```
protected void btnUpdate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Response.Write("abc");
    Node node = new Node();

    node.buildTree("all", "arraylist");
    al.Add(null);
    al = node.getArrayList();

    node.flushContent();
    DropDownList DropDownList1 = (DropDownList)DetailsView1.FindControl("DropDownList1");
    //DetailsView1.DropDownList1.Items.Clear();

    DropDownList1.Items.Add(new ListItem("ROOT", ""));
    foreach (pair item in al)
    {
        DropDownList1.Items.Add(new ListItem(item.getTitle(), item.getId()));
    }
}
```

i don't know whether my direction is right, but above code is not work~ anyone can help?

thanks

Comment: `but above code is not working`, what's the issue ? share your error if you have any.

Comment: just changed to OnDataBinding="btnUpdate_Click" is soloved. thanks